# How to keep a golang.org/x/net/websocket open?

Tags: go, websocket

I'm naively use [_, err := ws.Read(msg)](https://github.com/kaihendry/WebSocketHook/blob/master/server/main.go#L22) to keep a Web socket open in my code. I don't think it works reliably.

In other code I've noticed people doing a [sleep loop](https://github.com/skarnecki/gotail/blob/master/app.go#L56). What's the correct way to keep a Web socket open & stable? I assume the underlying library does ping/pongs?

Update: I'm pretty confident that the [client.go](https://github.com/kaihendry/WebSocketHook/blob/fd3fc976bf1ce5865b48005e3d4024682a1c9533/client/client.go) is to blame since it doesn't seem to redial after a disconnect is seen on the server. I made [a video demonstrating the issue](https://youtu.be/hmOI3MIIXIM).

Comment: I am also keen on seeing ping/pongs. For example if the client goes to sleep, I want to be able to tell what the time out is, last seen and such.

Comment: Starting to think it's my client that's the issue: https://github.com/kaihendry/WebSocketHook/tree/master/client It doesn't seem to be able to tell when it's disconnected.

Comment: Yes that's right. The idea is that the socket should stay open and robust until it receives that URL message payload. However in my example it's not robust.

Answer (score 7):

golang.org/x/net/websocket does not implement ping-pong from RFC 6455, but the gorilla websocket [implementation](http://github.com/gorilla/websocket) does.
Minimal example with Gorilla websocket

```
c := time.Tick(pingInterval)
go func(){
       for  _ := range c {
           if err := conn.WriteControl(Ping...); err != nil {
                 handle error 
            }
      }
   }()

          -----

conn.SetPongHandler(func(string) error { return conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pingInterval)) })
go func(){
      for {
           if _, _, err := conn.NextReader(); err != nil {
                handle error
           }
       }
    }()
```

Comment: Even with "github.com/gorilla/websocket", there isn't a minimal ping/pong example. I'm told https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/conn.go is a starting point, but it doesn't explain how to write a client binary & how to watch timeouts and such.

Comment: @hendry I add minimal example.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't quite understand what's implemented by client and what's implemented by the server. Could you make it clearer?

Comment: @hendry All on the same side. Peer WriteControl ping control message and then handle pong via PongHandler. Respond to ping via SetPingHandler would be enough for other side.

Comment: So they are on both sides, is that what you are saying? Need some time to come up with minimal example to try this. =)

Answer (score 6):

I misread your original question.

No you're doing it the right away. You basically need to block the handler from returning to keep the websocket connection alive. If you don't care about the message, just discard it and do nothing with it.

A common way people do it is to have a dedicated `Read` and `Write` goroutine, something like:

```
func fishHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    id := ws.RemoteAddr().String() + "-" + ws.Request().RemoteAddr + "-" + ws.Request().UserAgent()
    sockets[id] = ws

    go writePump(ws)
    readPump(ws)
}

func readPump(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    defer ws.Close()
    msg := make([]byte, 512)
    _, err := ws.Read(msg)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}

func writePump(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    // Hand the write messages here
}
```

Comment: I don't see why a dedicated `Write` goroutine is needed, considering that `websocket.Conn.Write` is internally protected by a mutex.

Comment: It also makes sense to call `ws.Close` after `ws.Read`, in case a binary or text message is accidentally sent by the client.

Comment: Checking `ws.Read`'s `err` doesn't make a lot of sense in this case either.

Comment: @TimCooper You're right, checking the error here doesn't make sense, I was just trying to keep as much as the original code from the question. As for a separate goroutine, it's more for readability, especially for `Read` when you're handling multiple Reads (I'm more thinking of a bigger picture with channels and stuff) But in the end, readability.

Comment: Hmm, if I am doing it right way, why am I have stability issues I wonder in my code? https://github.com/kaihendry/WebSocketHook/blob/master/server/main.go

Comment: What's an alternative to using the word "pump" in the read, and write? I don't think this word is descriptive enough. Stream?